# Parallel computing on two R servers using batchtools/BatchJobs

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use batchtools/BatchJobs for parallel computing on two unix-based R servers. I'm completely new to this and hence followed a few articles and package details to do this. I have added some links below:
[batchtools](https://mllg.github.io/batchtools/articles/batchtools.html#on-multiple-systems), 
[BatchJobs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/batchjobs/wikis/SSHCluster.wiki)

So far I have not really understood how to use batchtools for multi-machines. On the other hand, with BatchJobs I have better progress.

I made an ssh connection from the terminal first and execute the following lines:

```
reg = makeRegistry("TestExp")
reg$cluster.functions = makeClusterFunctionsSSH(worker = makeSSHWorker(nodename="sla19438"))  #By BatchJobs

#Test Function 
piApprox = function(n) {
  nums = matrix(runif(2 * n), ncol = 2)
  d = sqrt(nums[, 1]^2 + nums[, 2]^2)
  4 * mean(d <= 1)
}

set.seed(42)
piApprox(1000)
BatchJobs::batchMap(reg = reg, fun = piApprox, n = rep(1e7, 10))
getJobTable()
BatchJobs::submitJobs(reg = reg, resources = list(walltime = 3600, memory = 1024))
getStatus(reg = reg)
loadResult(reg = reg, id = 5)               
mean(sapply(1:10, loadResult, reg = reg))
```

It works and gives me the results but I can't see any indication of the jobs being run on the other machine (sla19438) when I run "top" in the terminal.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. Maybe there is some configuration needed but I don't see any material online which dumbs down the steps for a newbie like me.

Thanks